# Is it possible to make other javascript event listeners wait for an async event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'd like to hijack a web page (with Tampermonkey) that has a button with some event listeners, and finally a redirect.

Is there a way to add my own click event handler to the button, that makes an AJAX request, and waits for it to complete before moving on with the other event listeners, so my AJAX request definitely is completed before redirecting?

I know about [stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) but not how to "delay" propagation asynchronously.

Comment: No, that is not possible in general. There are however some [`ExtendableEvent`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent) which can do that, they are not fired everywhere though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot make other event handlers wait.  You *sometimes* can overwrite/hijack the existing functions, but this is often not possible using Tampermonkey and can get messy when it is possible (like in Firefox + Greasemonkey).

For clickable elements like buttons, one workaround is to **overlay the button**, set up listeners on it and then have them trigger the desired events on the original button when the time comes.

For example, consider the snippet below:

1. `#mainButton` and its code represent the original page.
2. The "Hijack" button simulates the running of your Tampermonkey script.
3. The "script" creates a div of the same size as the button and positions it over the button.  So, any clicks are caught by the div, not the button.
4. The intercept code does some asynchronous stuff that then triggers a click on the original button.

```js
//--------------------------
//--- The page's code:
//--------------------------
$("#mainButton").click ( function () {
    logline ("The button was clicked.");
} );

//------------------------------
//--- The script setup and code:
//------------------------------
$("#tmIntercept").click ( function () {
    logline ("==> Main button is now intercepted.");
    //this.disabled = true;
    $(this).attr ( {"disabled": true} );

    var targBtn     = $("#mainButton");
    var overlayDiv  = $('<div id="tmBtnOverlay">').css ( {
        'width':        targBtn.outerWidth (),
        'height':       targBtn.outerHeight (),
        'position':     'absolute',
        'top':          targBtn.offset ().top,
        'left':         targBtn.offset ().left,
        'z-index':      8888,
        'background':   "lime",
        'opacity':      "0.2"
    } )
    .appendTo ("body");

    overlayDiv.click ( function (zEvent) {
        //-- Guard against more global handlers.
        zEvent.stopImmediatePropagation ();

        logline ("Doing some AJAXy thing... <span>&nbsp;</span>");

        //-- Simulated AJAX call:
        setTimeout (doSomeAjaxyThing, 1111);
    } );
} );

function doSomeAjaxyThing () {
    $("#eventLog > p > span").first ().text ('Done.');

    //-- Now send required events to the original button:
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ("click", true, true);
    $("#mainButton")[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

function logline (str) {
    this.lineNumber = this.lineNumber + 1  ||  1;
    var lineDisplay = (1e15 + this.lineNumber + "").slice (-3);  //-- zero pad 3 places

    $("#eventLog").prepend ('<p>' + lineDisplay + ' &nbsp; ' + str + '</p>');
}
```

```css
#mainButton {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 0.3ex 2ex;
}
#eventLog {
    max-height: 50vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#eventLog > p {
    margin: 0.3ex 2ex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><button id="mainButton">The Button</button></p>

<p><button id="tmIntercept" autocomplete="off">Hijack the button</button></p>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Event Log:</legend>
    <div id="eventLog"></div>
</fieldset>
```

---

**Notes:**

1. In some cases you may be tempted to directly call the page's code.  But it is generally much simpler, robust, and secure to trigger events instead.
2. This is just a demo of the overlay process.  In practice, the simple absolute positioning may need tweaking.  (Usually wrapping the target node in a relatively positioned div and adjusting the offsets.)  That is beyond the scope of this question.